# Validation framework for Excel Sheets

Tags: java, regex, excel, apache-poi

I have an excel document which is used by the users to enter data according to the template and upload it back.
Now i have many sheets in the workbook and each sheet have many cells with different validations.

```
Validations like:
1. The cell data should be only numeric
2. The cell data should be in a specific format xxx-xxx
3. The cell data should be a date in yyyy-mm-dd format
```

etc...

Is their a framework available which can do the job ? Like i just have to configure the data allowed in a cell(using regular expressions etc..) 
and the framework will take care of the validations.

Answer (score 0):

There are frameworks to access Excel files from Java. Like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). But I don't know a framework which does what you described.

Maybe it's a better idea to add this validation to the excel file so that the user can't input invalid data.

Comment: No i need the validation in the server itself. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in validating excel file upload in the server.
Although it can be done using if else condition like:

1. The cell data should be only numeric

```
if (cell.getCellType() != CellType.NUMERIC) {
  // throw exception or print print help message
}
```

2. The cell data should be a date in yyyy-mm-dd format

```
if (!DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
  // throw exception or print print help message
}
```

However, validating Date type cells and applying regex is tricky.